# Android Realm storing int[] and String[]

Tags: java, android, arrays, realm

Is there a way to store an int[] and a String[], other than creating a new object that contains those, and then storing it in a realmList

I have an object which takes the parameters of a String, int[], and String[]. you cant store int[], and String[] in realm so I made an object

```
public class Workouts extends RealmObject {

    private String workout;

    public Workouts() {

    }

    public Workouts(String workout) {
        this.workout = workout;
    }

    public String getWorkout() {
        return workout;
    }

    public void setWorkout(String workout) {
        this.workout = workout;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Multiplier extends RealmObject {

    private int multiplier;

    public Multiplier() {

    }

    public Multiplier(int multiplier) {
        this.multiplier = multiplier;
    }

    public int getMultiplier() {
        return multiplier;
    }

    public void setMultiplier(int multiplier) {
        this.multiplier = multiplier;
    }
}
```

and then I store them like
RealmList multipliers;
RealmList workouts;

I am wondering if there is a way I can store these by just using an array instead of a RealmList

Comment: We need more detail here

Answer (score 8):

Emanuele from Realm here. Right now there's no other way other than wrapping String or int and use RealmList on those. This is for several reasons, including being able to use Realm file on different platforms. Is this an acceptable solution in your use-case or is it a pain?

If you would like, this gist demonstrates how one would use a RealmList to store a group of primitive values within a RealmObject. https://gist.github.com/cmelchior/1a97377df0c49cd4fca9

Comment: It makes things more difficult, because I have to create the objects and change parameters which makes it a lot harder to dynamically add stuff to my array

Comment: Where, and how can I pull the .realm file off my device to view in the realm browser

Comment: The default Realm file is located in the directory specified by `context.getFilesDir()`. Unless you use the emulator (or a rooted device) you cannot pull this file from the phone because of permissions, but you can store the Realm file in external storage if you like, and at that point it is reachable.

Comment: Regarding this, I need to add a object in my realm database, but that object contains a LatLng object inside (which is a google maps class, and I do not have acces to its code) Is it possible to add it somehow?

Comment: It is not possible to store third party classes. What you can do is extract whatever values you need to recreate a LatLng object and store such values instead.

Comment: Hey @Emanuelez has this solution updated in the last few months? Is there a better way to do this now?

Answer (score 4):

Create RealmString class as below

```
public class RealmString extends RealmObject {
    private String val;
    public RealmString(){
    }

    public RealmString(String value) {
        this.val = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return val;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.val = value;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return val;
    }
}
```

Create new class

```
public class RealmStringDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<RealmList<RealmString>> {

    @Override
    public RealmList<RealmString> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
                                              JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

        RealmList<RealmString> realmStrings = new RealmList<>();
        JsonArray stringList = json.getAsJsonArray();

        for (JsonElement stringElement : stringList) {
            realmStrings.add(new RealmString(stringElement.getAsString()));
        }

        return realmStrings;
    }
}
```

If you are using realm with retrofit then add following lines to your retrofit builder class

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .setExclusionStrategies(new ExclusionStrategy() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
                        return f.getDeclaringClass().equals(RealmObject.class);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .registerTypeAdapter(new TypeToken<RealmList<RealmString>>() {
                }.getType(), new RealmStringDeserializer())
                .create();

        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(NetworkConstants.BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build();
        }
```

Comment: `realmStrings.add(new RealmString(stringElement.getAsString()));` was the saviour

Comment: I've missed the customized GSON object at Retrofit initialisation, until that I landed on call's onFailure() everytime... now I can reach onResponse()! You've helped me a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't like using RealmString and RealmInt. How for example will you keep track of deleting them again when the list changes?

I've built a custom solution for the Realm - GSON (Retrofit) combi, where they share the same model object. I tested only 10 json files. Let me know if you find any problems and I'll perfectionize this.

Firstly, create a String instead of an int[] or String[] in your RealmObject:

```
/* 
 * Languages this user selected. Comma separated String.
 */
@SerializedName("languages")
private String languages;
```

Then create getters and setters for it. Note that `StringUtils.join()` is my own method, if none of the libraries you use has it then you can find it anywhere on the net.

```
/**
 * All user languages.
 */
public void setLanguagesFromList(List<String> languages) {

    String languagesStr = languages == null ? "" : StringUtils.join(languages, ",");
    if (!TextUtils.equals(this.languages, languagesStr)) {
        setDirty(true);
    }
    this.languages = languagesStr;
}

/**
 * Returns an unmodifiableList with all user languages.
 * <p>
 * Use setLanguagesFromList with a new list to make changes.
 *
 * @return
 */
public List<String> getLanguagesList() {

    return Collections.unmodifiableList(
            languages == null ? new ArrayList<>() :
                    Arrays.asList(languages.split(",")));
}
```

If you use this getter a lot, you might wanna create a `List<String>` that is not saved in the database (@Ignore) but is used to speed up this method (so that parsing is only done on changes / first access).

Then create a Deserializer for GSON/Retrofit:

```
/**
 * Used so that string (or any other primitive) arrays are parsed int one String. Realm cannot handle String arrays.
 */
public class RealmPrimitiveArrayDeserializer implements
    JsonDeserializer<String> {

private final static String KOMMA = ",";

  @Override
  public String deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
                          JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

    if (json.isJsonNull()) {
        return null;
    }

    if (json.isJsonArray()) {

        StringBuilder targetStringBuilder = null;
        JsonArray stringList = json.getAsJsonArray();

        for (JsonElement element : stringList) {

            if (element.isJsonPrimitive()) {

                if (targetStringBuilder == null) {
                    targetStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                }

                targetStringBuilder.append(element.getAsString());
                targetStringBuilder.append(KOMMA);
            }
        }

        if (targetStringBuilder != null && targetStringBuilder.length() > 0) { 

            // remove the last komma:
            targetStringBuilder.deleteCharAt(targetStringBuilder.length() - 1);

            return targetStringBuilder.toString();
        }
    }

    return json.getAsString();
  }
}
```

Add this to your GSON configuration used by Retrofit:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(new TypeToken<String>() {
                }.getType(), new RealmPrimitiveArrayDeserializer());
```

That's it. Good luck.

Comment: @here check this out, why this answer seems better:

https://hackernoon.com/realmlist-realmstring-is-an-anti-pattern-bfc10efb7ca5#.8shy7ljzm

offtopic: picked your solution